# java.sql.SQLException: Could not find database ID X name 'database'.

Tags: java, sql-server

When I run all my JUnit tests, which uses a MS SQL Server database, I'm getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not find database ID X, name 'database_name'. The database may be offline. Wait a few minutes and try again.

or sometimes the `java.sql.Connection` object is closed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the problem when I turned AUTO CLOSE setting to OFF, right after database creation:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST123;
ALTER DATABASE [TEST123] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF WITH NO_WAIT;
```

Check it out: [Worst Practice: Allowing AutoClose on SQL Server Databases](http://www.itprotoday.com/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases)

Comment: The default for AUTO_CLOSE is False....(unless your model database has been explicitly set to enable AutoClose). So how is it enabled in the first place?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server v17.2, if I use create database command as it is, it gets created with AUTO_CLOSE True, maybe if you create a new database using the wizard it will be created with false as default value... It's a local database used only for development installed with all default options.

Comment: -> "unless your model database has been explicitly set to enable AutoClose" - which it shouldn't be. Fix the cause , not the symptom